# jquery regexp email validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use a regular expression to validate an email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses)

I have tried all the standard options, but none have helped with email: *blablabla-K@kiev.foxtrot.ua*

client function for my custom validator in asp.net webforms:

```
function requiredFields(source, args) {

                var reg = new RegExp('/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/');

                var email = $('#tbEmail').val();
                args.IsValid = ((email.length > 0) && (reg.test(email)));
 }
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses

Comment: You can also check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: thank u. tried second answer - excelent :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#txtEmail').blur(function() {
  if(validateEmail('txtEmail'))
  {
      alert('Email is valid');
  }
  else
  {
      alert('Invalid Email Address');
  }
 });
});
function validateEmail(txtEmail){
   var a = document.getElementById(txtEmail).value;
   var filter = /^((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*?)\s*;?\s*)+/;
if(filter.test(a)){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
}
</script>
```

Email Address:

```
< input type='text' id='txtEmail' />
```

For Live Demo Click Here[1](http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/LQAYy/)